# Is there a good way to get the view callable itself through introspection with the Pyramid framework

Tags: pyramid

I am trying to use the Pyramid introspection interface for getting a list of all views for a given resource type from a view callable.  I can use the following to get a set of introspectables for view configurations that were added:

```
@view_config(...)
def view_callable(context, request):
  introspector = request.registry.introspector
  for view_int in introspector.get_category('views'):
    view_int = view_int['introspectable']
```

Though I didn't find any official documentation on the format of the discriminator, from here it seems that view_int.discriminator[1] is the type of the context from traversal, view_int.discriminator[2] is the view name, view_int.discriminator[3] is the route name, etc.

However, how does one then get the view callable function itself for this view?  IIntrospectable doesn't seem to offer a way to get this?

Is there a better way to get a list of all registerd view callables based on the route_name, context type, etc. at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reviewing the source I found the following simple solution that works.  Though, I'm not sure if this is stable as I didn't find it in the official documentation.

```
for view in request.registry.introspector.get_category('views'):
    context = view['introspectable']['context']
    view_callable_class = view['introspectable']['callable']
    view_callable_method_name = view['introspectable']['attr']
```